# Usage of the article with a repeated subject

Tags: articles

> A boy ran, a boy skipped.

Is such a sentence correct? I don't know much about usage of the article with repeated subjects. The boy described in the sentence has not appeared in the story before.

Comment: @ userr2684291 Thank you for correcting my initial post. A subject can't be "reiterative", as opposed to "style", right?

Comment: I wouldn't know. *Repeated* sounded more normal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's perfectly correct (except you need a semi-colon not a comma unless you're making a longer list of things different boys did).

It means there are (at least) two boys, one who ran, and one who skipped.

If the intention were to have one boy one would say "A boy ran; the same boy skipped" or "a boy ran and skipped" or "a boy ran, skipped[ and fell over]".

It's a somewhat unusual construction, but I might expect to see it in something like:

"After they were let out from school class 5B tended to be a little unruly: a boy ran, a boy skipped, a boy chased a dog, and, one particularly criminal boy, forged cheques."